# vector subscript out of range when debugging

Tags: c++, vector

The code is a part of build a min-heap. It seems that the following sentence went wrong.

```
if ((child < (int)heap.size() - 1) && (heap[leftchild].cost > heap[leftchild + 1].cost))
```

But I can't figure out how to manage it. Is there anyone offering some help? Thank you very much!!

```
void heap_adjust_down(vector<rt_node> & rt, vector<h_node> & heap)
{
    cout << "the" << heap.size() << "times" << endl;
    cout << heap[heap.size()-1].id << endl;
    int child;
    for (int i = heap.size() / 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << " into build heap, i = " << i << endl;
        int leftchild = 2 * i + 1;
        h_node temp_h;

        for (temp_h = heap[i]; leftchild < (int)heap.size(); i = child)
        {
            leftchild = 2 * i + 1;
            cout << "  into percdown" << endl;
            child = leftchild;
            if ((child < (int)heap.size() - 1) && (heap[leftchild].cost > heap[leftchild + 1].cost))
            {
                child++;
            }
            if (heap[child].cost < temp_h.cost )
            {
                heap[i] = heap[child];
                rt[i].h_pos = child;
            }
            else break;
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        }
        heap[i] = temp_h;
        rt[i].h_pos = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a please-solve-my-problem-for-me site.

Comment: And what happens if `leftchild == vector.size() - 1`?

Comment: The last vector element doesn't have a +1 neighbor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is more likely this line:

```
if (heap[child].cost < temp_h.cost )
```

This line does not have the check for `child < size` like you similarly did on the previous if statement. Also, in the second iteration of the inner for loop, `leftchild` will double, at least, (and so will child). This does not seem to be your intent. (`leftchild` will double because you are setting `i = child` in the loop iterator.)

The inner for loop needs to be rethought. For example, your test expression tests that `leftchild < size`, but then you immediately recalculate `leftchild` based on `i`, kindof nullifying that test.

Comment: Thanks, the problem solved as the approach you mentioned!